# Mysql InnoDB Operating system error number 32 in a file operation on Windows

Tags: mysql, innodb

Since a few days ago, MySQL server on my Windows machine was not successful on closing itself. I found multiple instance of these lines in the MySQL error log:

```
InnoDB: Operating system error number 32 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means that another program is using InnoDB's files.
InnoDB: This might be a backup or antivirus software or another instance
InnoDB: of MySQL. Please close it to get rid of this error.
```

I have plenty of free spaces, the server is installed for months, the version is 5.1.22-rc-community-log on Windows XP SP3, and I have used only one Windows account to create and execute MySQL service.

Following Greg's answer, I found through `ProcessExplorer` that there's another MySQL service running with a different name. I kill it and all run fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the file is in use by another program then [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) could help you track down which one has it open.   I assume you've checked you only have one copy of MySQL running.

Comment: Let's just repeat `I assume you've checked you only have one copy of MySQL running.` since I can't be the only dummy out there... ;)

Comment: For me the problem was a mysqld process still running in the background from earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a conflict. Make sure to stop the mysqld service and then double-check if it's really not running anymore, then restart the service. Also, when it's back up, make sure to run checks on your tables and see if there is any damage.

My assumption is based on the [operating system error codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operating-system-error-codes.html) in the MySQL docs.

Comment: It could be caused by Antivirus software scanning

Answer (score 3):

You can follow these steps:

1. Open TaskManager
2. Kill the **mysqld.exe** process.
3. `cd E:\apps\db\mysql-5.5.25-win32\bin`
4. Run: `mysqld --install MySQL`
5. Run: `mysqladmin -u root start`