# InnoDB: The error means that another program is using InnoDB's files. Getting OS error 32 in MYSQL error log

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

Errors:

> [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 32 in a file operation.
>
> [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means that another program is using InnoDB's files.

Configuration changes in my.cnf:

```
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine=MYISAM
```

Can this error happen because of the configuration change above that is been done.

Checked process explorer and could see two processes running of mysql and showing under "process explorer" output having the two different PID's at the time we see the errors.

Comment: Probably a good start as you've changed your `my.cnf` file to restart MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql InnoDB "error 32" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283661/mysql-innodb-error-32-on-windows)